# Developer Options in Android 5.1.1

Tags: 5.1-lollipop

I have turn on my developer option in my Samsung galaxy grand price. how to hide the developer options in android 5.1.1?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

- Go to Setting.
- Tap on Apps/Application, Navigate to all apps.
- Now, here you have to find Settings app.
- Open the Setting app, There is a button "Clear Data", Press it, Again press OK.
- Your Developer Option get Hidden now.

Hope that helps !!